Find the common ratio
Suppose $P$ is an interior point of a triangle $ABC$ such that the ratios
$\dfrac{d(A,BC)}{d(P,CA)} , \dfrac{d(P,BC)}{d(C,AB)} , \dfrac{d(B,CA)}{d(P,AB)}$
are all equal. Find the common value of the ratios. Here $d(X,YZ)$ denotes the
perpendicular distance from a point $X$ to the line $YZ$.

Here is my approach:
$$\dfrac{d(A,BC)}{d(P,CA)} , \dfrac{d(C,BC)}{d(P,AB)} , \dfrac{d(B,CA)}{d(P,AB)} = k$$
$$\dfrac{[BCP]+[APB]+[IPC]}{[ABC]} = \dfrac{3}{k}$$
$$\implies \dfrac{[ABC]}{[ABC]} = \dfrac{3}{k}$$
$$\implies 1 = \dfrac{3}{k}$$
$$\implies k = 3$$
Is my solution correct and is there a better solution for this?

Can you please check the second line of your problem statement? There, the second ratio given is $\dfrac{d\left(P, BC\right)} {d\left(C, AB\right)}$. We think that should be $\dfrac {d\left(C, AB\right)}{d\left(P, BC\right)}$. Furthermore, you need to explain how you obtained $k= 3$ from $1=\dfrac{1}{k}$.

The value of $k$ is $3$ is correct. But I'm pretty sure that the expression of ratio should be: $$ \frac{d(A,BC)}{d(P,BC)} =  \frac{d(B,CA)}{d(P,CA)}  =  \frac{d(C,AB)}{d(P,AB)}$$

@YNK,  I corrected it

@tToE I corrected that too
